# how to get entire object using navParams - Ionic 3 Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

currently I am passing data object from one page to another page (in Modal).

I have 8 parameters to pass to the modal view.

```
this.firstParam = navParams.get("firstPassed");
this.secondParam = navParams.get("secondPassed");
.
.
.
this.eightParam = navParams.get("eightPassed");
```

How can I get entire object data using one call

```
this.data = navParams.getAll(); //something like this
```

I am unable to find a method in a documentation to get an entire object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to do like that. You can send all at once like below.

**Note:** Declare a data transfer object like `DtoMy`

*Dto-my.ts*

```
export class DtoMy {
    firstPassed: string;
    secondPassed: string;

    //your other properties
}
```

**send**

```
let dtoMy = new DtoMy();
dtoMy.firstPassed= 'firstPassed';
dtoMy.secondPassed= 'secondPassed';
//your other values

const myModal = this.modalCtrl.create('MyModalPage', { data: dtoMy });
    myModal.onDidDismiss(data => { });
    myModal.present();
```

**Receive:**

*my-modal-page.ts*

```
data :DtoMy;

constructor(private navParams: NavParams, private modalCtrl: ModalController) {
      this.data = this.navParams.get('data');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to get an entire object in the second page, you can try the following:

**To send:**

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams : NavParams){}

 public userObject = 
 {
  firstName : "peter",
  lastName  : "haddad"
 }

clickMe()
{
  this.navCtrl.push(SecondPage,this.userObject);
}
```

You import both the NavController and the NavParams, then use the method [`push()`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#push) that will contain the object you want to pass and it will navigate to the second page.

**In the second Page:**

```
export class SecondPage 
{

 userObject;
 userName;

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams){}

  ngOnInit()
  {
  this.userObject = this.navParams.data;
  this.userName   = this.userObject.firstName;
  console.log(this.userObject);
  }
}
```

Here you can access the object by using the instance member [`data`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavParams/#data) of `NavParams`, to be able to access the `lastName`, you can do this `this.lastName=this.userObject.lastName`

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
console.log(this.navParams.data)
}
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to your answer.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18630961)